# How to change in Postgresql only the columns that have new values and keep the others unchanged?

Tags: postgresql

In the following table, I would like to change the `match_date` and `referee_id` columns, but keep all the other columns unchanged.

Right now when I try to change `match_date` and `referee_id` columns all the other columns change to `NULL`. How can I avoid that?

```
UPDATE matches
SET
  match_date = ${match_date},
  referee_id = ${referee_id},
  field_id = ${field_id},
  played = ${played},
  team_1_goals = ${team_1_goals},
  team_2_goals = ${team_2_goals}
WHERE match_id = ${match_id}
RETURNING *
```

Comment: Simply leave the other fields alone. `UPDATE matches SET match_date = ${match_date}, referee_id = ${referee_id} WHERE match_id = ${match_id} RETURNING *`. A am afraid that your query is SQL injection prone though.

Comment: But I want to use the same query when updating other columns in different points in time. Do I have to create one query to update every column? For instance in other part of the app I want to update team_1_goals and team_2_goals, can I use the same query?

Comment: Then can you try to generate the query text dynamically instead of updating column by column? What middle tier language are you using?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: I am using React and Node, with Express and Massive.

Comment: Javascript. You can certainly do that.